# How to concatenate a datetime into a textbox in c# asp.net to show just date

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, datetime

How do I concatenate a nullable datetime into a textbox in c# asp.net to show just date?
When i load the date into the textbox I get below in textbox:

2014-04-26 00:00:00.000

But I just want the date any ideas? Cant get tostring to display what i want.
I am calling the value like below:

```
 txtDateExpected.Text = loadVisitDetails.expectedDate.ToString();
```

Comment: How hard did you look?  I searched for `c# date tostring` and got this : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Its different as im using a nullable datetime

Comment: @wubblyjuggly It is as simple as `yourNullable.Value.Date.ToString()`

Comment: @wubblyjuggly You should also mention things like that in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can get only Date part by using `Date` property of `DateTime` class:

```
 txtDateExpected.Text = loadVisitDetails.expectedDate != null ? loadVisitDetails.expectedDate.Date.ToString() : "";
```

or:

```
if(loadVisitDetails.expectedDate != null)
   txtDateExpected.Text = loadVisitDetails.expectedDate.Date.ToString();
```

Check [Here DateTime.Date MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: OP added in comments that `expectedDate` is nullable. Can you add that check too?

Comment: `ToString()` will may produce results with different formats, if you don't specify the culture or an explicit format

Comment: what you suggest andrew..you can share that as well for correction

Comment: why are you passing "d" please explain it

Answer (score 1):

Use `string.Format` to form a representation you want:

```
DateTime? dt = loadVisitDetails.expectedDate;
txtDateExpected.Text = (dt == null) ?
                        String.Empty :
                        String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", dt);
```

Comment: This would mean you are bound with a specific format. Where OP just needed the date part.

Comment: Also, surely more readable to use `dt.ToString()` rather than `string.Format`?

Comment: well that's a matter of taste;)

Comment: @Yahya, don't you think format matters? are you always sure about `ToString()` result? PS. `Thread.Culture` and `Thread.UICulture` are tricky